# Assembly reference in reference project

Tags: c#, reference

I have project P that references assembly A (external dll). Now I want to use Project P in Project T, so I reference P in T, but when compiling, I get a Error CS0012 The type 'A.type' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
Do I really need to reference both P (project reference) and A (assembly reference) whenever i want to use P in a different project?

---

A bit more detail:
dll A provides a single class A.S (+ some enums) for communication with an external device, P provides a wrapper around A.S, where I extracted the interface and derived a class from interface IS and S, and othother class that uses

```
public class S : A.S, IS { // override some functions to add logging }

public class C
{
    public C(IS s) { ... }
}
```

Now in Project T (actually unittests) I use it like

```
public class Tests
    {
        C c;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            var s = new S();
            c = new C(s);
            ...
        }
```

And in `var c = new C(s);` is where the error shows up.

Comment: Is `A.Type` being used directly in project T? For example, via a return type or method argument type? If so, you will need to directly reference the assembly that defines `A.Type`.

Comment: Can you show the code where this error is happening?

Comment: To clarify my comment above: Assembly A defines `class TypeA`. Assembly B defines `class TypeB` with a method `MethodB` declared as `TypeA MethodB()`. Assembly C calls `TypeB.MethodB()` - now assembly C must explicitly reference assembly A.